# $3$-Sylows of $A_7$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

**The problem states: "Find the number and the structure of the Sylow $3$-subgroups of $A_7$."**

- Things I know:

-No problem with the structure, it is $C_3 \times C_3$ as they're no elements of order $9$ in $A_7$.

-From Sylow theorems we know that $n_3 \ | \ 280$ and $n_3 \equiv 1 $ mod $ (3)$.

- Best idea:

-The order of the conjugacy class of every $3$-cycle is $70$, so as all the Sylow are cojugated maybe we can do something with this, but I don't think I comprehend that part of the theory enough.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: How do you know that the number should be $70$? What have you tried? Are you familiar with the Sylow theorems? What do they tell you?

Comment: Wikipedia has a page with some things about the A7. I've been thinking 2 hours and I don't have time to explain everything. Sylow theorems don't say much as they give me so many options, I can only conclude the structure from them I guess, that is $C_3xC_3$, I don't know if I can do something with the second one.

Comment: Why should they be a multiple of $140$? Is it related to the order of the conjugacy class?

Comment: Please share your progress so far.

Comment: I think that is a waste of time, I just need a little help with the way of finding the number not replicating all that I did wrong (and I don't see why it should be 280).

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: It's not a waste of time; it's a requirement here.

Comment: By Sylow 3rd theorem, the number can be $1, 4, 7, 10, 28, 40, 70, 280$

Comment: This is a good problem, the community may profit from such questions, unfortunately, it is not "sold" with the right story. Instead of inserting your thoughts in the comments, a much much better strategy now and later is to collect all you know, and present the facts in the text of the question. That observation of a $C_3\times C_3$ structure for each Sylow $3$-subgroup is almost the solution. You could have inserted any kind of related information, best the source, the level, which is the story with $A_5$ and/or $A_6$ instead of $A_7$, show explicitly one $3$-Sylow subgroup, give a scheme...

Comment: Please consider rewriting the question, adding context is a must, take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question , if rewritten, i will upvote!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the effort of reshaping the question, it is a benefit for the community, exactly such a statement if best suited for a quick and full understanding of the question. **And** for a later search, many users will profit from this sample application of Sylow's theorems. No more text, no less text. Upvoted, of course!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group $A_7$ has order $7!/2 = 3^2\cdot(2^3\cdot 5\cdot 7)$. Recall for this special case the consequences of the three [Sylow theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems):

Let $\Bbb S$ be the set of $3$-Sylow subgroups of $A_7$, then $\Bbb S$ is not empty,
and in fact let us write explicitly one such group:
$$
S=\Big\langle\ (123)\ ,\ (456)\ \Big\rangle\in\Bbb S\ ,
$$
each $H\in \Bbb S$ has $3^2$ elements, each two $3$-Sylow subgroups in $\Bbb S$ are conjugated, and denoting by $n=n_3$ the cardinality of $\Bbb S$ we have:

- $n$ divides the index $2^3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ of $S$ in $A_7$,
- $n$ is one modulo $3$,
- $n=|A_7:N|$, where $N$ is the normalizer of $S$ in $A_7$.

Let us use this information. What does a conjugated version of $S$ look like? It is also generated by two commuting cycles $s=(abc)$ and $t=(def)$.
How many chances are there to choose them, so that different groups $H(s,t):=\langle s,t\rangle$ occur? It is clear that given such a Sylow group $H\in\Bbb S$ we can immediately isolate its two subgroups of $3$-cycles, so we can pick two generators $s$ and $t$, and there are some choices to do so, we can replace $s$ by $s^2$ and/or $t$ by $t^2$ and after these steps we may want to switch $s$ and $t$.
Note that the set $\{a,b,c\}$ determines the subgroup $\langle s\rangle $ of $H(s,t)$. Similarly,
the set $\{d,e,f\}$ determines the subgroup $\langle t\rangle $ of $H(s,t)$.
Let $g$ be the remaining symbol.

Now we can count, there are $7$ choices for $g$, then $\binom 63$ choices for the set $\{a,b,c\}$, then the set of the remained symbols $\{d,e,f\}$ is determined, each such choice leads to a group $H(\ (abc)\ ,\ (def)\ )$, and when counting these groups, exchanging $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{d,e,f\}$ leads to the same group. We have thus listed all conjugates of $S$; their number is
$$
7\cdot\binom 63\cdot\frac 12=7\cdot 20\cdot \frac12=70\ .
$$
$\square$

---

So the wanted number is $n=n_3=70$; as a check, it divides the index $2^3\cdot 5\cdot 7=280$, and it is $1$ modulo three.

---

We are done, but let us give an alternative. Which is the normalizer $N$ of $S$ in $A_7$? First of all, the nine elements of $S$ are in $N$. Then $(23)(56)$ is also in $N$, conjugating with these elements brings the $S$-generators $s=(123)$ into $s^2=(132)$, and $t=(456)$ into $t^2=(465)$. And there is also $(14)(2536)$, also in $N$; we get it when trying to switch over $(123)$ and $(456)$. The first idea is to use $(14)(25)(36)$, which is not even, so we use an other odd permutation to adjust. So $N$ is a group with at least $36$ elements, which makes $|\Bbb S|=|A_7:N|$ have at most $7!/2/36=70$ elements. The divisors of $70$ which are one modulo three are $1,7,10,70$, and it is easy to eliminate the first three choices as being too small. In particular, the normalizer of $S$ is
$$
N=\langle\ (123)\ ,\ (456)\ ,\ (23)(56)\ ,\ (14)(2536)\ \rangle\ .
$$

---

*Note:* I decided to submit the answer; from the comments, OP knows the structure $C_3\times C_3$ of each $3$-Sylow subgroup, to have the list of all such subgroups it is important to use the cycle structure. (Explicitly,
for $C_3\times C_3$ there is a lot of choices of two generators, but using also the cycle structure, we have less choices, and can count.)

---

*Note:* A computer aided solution, here using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: A7 = AlternatingGroup(7)
sage: S = A7.sylow_subgroup(3)
sage: N = A7.normalizer(S)
sage: A7.order() / N.order()
70
sage: S
Subgroup generated by [(4,5,6), (1,2,3)] of (Alternating group of order 7!/2 as a permutation group)
sage: N
Subgroup generated by [(4,5,6), (2,3)(4,6), (1,2,3), (1,4,3,6)(2,5)] of (Alternating group of order 7!/2 as a permutation group)
```

It may be useful to complement the theoretical part with explicit "dirty" experiences, for me this was working fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, my greatest mistake was loosing time with the conjugates of the product of $3$-cycles, when it is obvious that we will have them in the total group ($C_3 \times C_3$). Seeing this answer made me comprehend the huge power of knowing the conjugacy classes, which I already thought it was really useful but I had never done anything with it. Thank you so much, I rewrote the question in gratitude as more people can see it.